# How browsers load images? Thumbs are necessary?

Tags: html, css, dom, get, browser

When i create gallery on my website, i need thumbs? Or i can use full images and resize it with css?

For example, i have gallery like that: http://otomoto.pl/renault-20-r-20-1-6-1-6-gtl-C21940610.html
If every images will be resizing with css, then browser will load the same image many times or one? Page will load faster when it will be image01thumb.png, image01normal.png, image01full.png? Or just image01full.png?

Comment: If you found the answers helpful, please do choose one as your selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you resize with CSS, then the client will have to download the whole image and resize it, which is not good in terms of bandwidth. You want some thumbnail-sized images so that you can send a small image to the client rather than having to send the full thing.

Comment: But browser will donwload it one time when i put the same image in many places?

Comment: If you use the same reference (URL) to it, but on many pages, a browser will (should) cache it and just download it once, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of gallery you have. Obviously when you are using thumbnails the client does not have to download the full image if he never sees the full sized one. But if you have a dynamic gallery where for instance you make an image bigger with a tween/animation on mouse over it might be preferable that the image already is loaded so the transition goes smoothly.